# Why is that I'm getting "Invalid DateTime" in the following Luxon/Moment code?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

```
const dt = DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date))
// dt => DateTime {ts: 1516876197386, zone: LocalZone, loc: Locale, invalid: "unparsable", weekData: null, …}
return dt.toFormat('yyyy/mm/dd')
```

The result is: `Invalid DateTime`. Why is this and how to fix it?

Luxon's docs: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toFormat

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso):

> Create a DateTime from an ISO 8601 string

accepts ISO string, while you are passing a JavaScript Date.

You can use Date's `toISOString()` or luxon [`fromJSDate`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromjsdate)

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const dt = DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString());
console.log(dt.toFormat('yyyy/MM/dd'));
const dt2 = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date());
console.log(dt2.toFormat('yyyy/MM/dd'));
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Moreover, note that you have to use uppercase `MM` to print month instead of lowercase `mm` that stands for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fromJSDate like: `luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date())`